# Vue2 - Composition API - TypeScript - Calling child component method

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am building a web-app using Vue2 with Composition API, and TypeScript.

I have a form which is made up of separate custom components. When the user clicks "save" I want to run the `validate` method present on each of the components, but I cannot seem to get TypeScript to agree with the actual results of compilation.

Here is a super simplified version of the issue with just a single component.

**Component**

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
export default defineComponent({
  methods: {
    validate() {
      let validationResult = { isValid: false };
      // [...validation logic]
      return validationResult;
    }
  }
});
```

**Parent**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <my-component>
    <button @click="save">save</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { defineComponent, onMounted, toRefs, ref } from "@vue/composition-api";
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    MyComponent,
  },
  setup() {
    const myComponentInst = ref<typeof MyComponent | null>(null);
    
    return { myComponentInst };
  },
  methods: {
    submit() {
      const result = this.myComponentInst?.methods?.validate();

      //[...] etc. perform save if everything is valid
    }
  }
});
```

TypeScript is ok with the above, but `methods` in `const result = this.myComponentInst?.methods?.validate();` is always `null` at runtime.

Looking at `this.myComponentInst` in a debugger, I see:

```js
VueComponent {_uid: 15, _isVue: true, $options: {...}, [...etc], validate: f(), ...}
```

It directly contains the `methods` from the component - including `validate`. But, if I write `const result = this.myComponentInst.validate();` I get the following compilation error:

```
Property 'validate' does not exist on type 'VueProxy<{ ...9 more }>' Vetur(2339)
```

But I know that this is the correct structure. When I initiate the instances with `const myComponentInst = ref<any>(null);` everything works... but of course then I lose my typing.

Is there another way to get the component instance in such a way that Vetur/TypeScript pre-compiler will not complain about it, and will actually work at runtime?

Am I just referencing the method incorrectly?

Comment: This type of approach seems to me to defeat the purpose of composition API. The validation logic should be in a composable that you can just use in any component. Then you wouldn't need to try and use a component as a bridge.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I ended up finding a different path to resolve this. I am using DevExtreme component library for the inputs. This has a "validation engine". Each one of my components then gets a name. Then the parent can activate validation based on the child components that it has. Thanks.